# write list of AD User fields to CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling a subset of data from a long list of users I want to populate into a CSV.  I can do the following which prints to screen the list, how do I then write each iteration as a row in a CSV?

```
foreach ($User in $UserList)
{
    Write-Host $User.Enabled           #Enabled
    if ($User.Country -eq "CA" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "CANADA")
    {
        Write-Host "Canada"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "LUX" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "LUXEMBOURG")
    {
        Write-Host "Luxembourg"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "BRL" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "BRAZIL")
    {
        Write-Host "Brazil"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "USA" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "US")
    {
        Write-Host "America"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "UNITED KINGDOM" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "GB")
    {
        Write-Host "United Kingdom"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "HONG KONG" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "HK")
    {
        Write-Host "Hong Kong"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "INDIA" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "IN")
    {
        Write-Host "India"
    }
    elseif ($User.Country -eq "AUSTRALIA" -OR $User.DistinguishedName -like "AU")
    {
        Write-Host "Australia"
    }
    Write-Host $User.SamAccountName     #Login ID
    Write-Host $User.GivenName          #First Name
    Write-Host $User.Surname            #Last Name
    Write-Host $User.Title              #Title
    Write-Host $User.mail               #E-Mail
    Write-Host $User.LastLogonDate      #Last Login Date
    if ($User.accountExpires -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Host $User.AccountExpirationDate
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "N/A"
    }                                   #Expiration Date
    # Write-Host $User.                   #Password Expiration
    Write-Host $User.Department         #Department
    Write-Host $User.Office             #Floor
    Write-Host $User.OfficePhone        #Office Number
    Write-Host $User.MobilePhone        #Mobile Number
    Write-Host $User.whenCreated        #Created Date
    Write-Host $User.whenChanged        #Changed Date
}
```

Comment: First, create custom objects that have the properties that yoou want (`New-Object PSCustomObject)` next add each object to an arraylist. Once you have all the objects in the arraylist, export it to a csv (`Export-CSV`)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a `switch`, `Export-Csv`, and calculated properties with `Select-Object`:

```
$UserList | Select-Object -Property @(
    'SamAccountName', 'Enabled', 'GivenName', 'Surname'
    'Title'
    'Mail'
    'LastLogonDate'
    'Department', 'Office'
    'OfficePhone', 'MobilePhone'
    'WhenCreated', 'WhenChanged'
    @{
        Label = 'AccountExpires'
        Expression = {
            if ($PSItem.accountExpires -eq 1) {
                $PSItem.AccountExpirationDate
            } else {
                'N/A'
            }
        }
    }
    @{
        Label = 'Country'
        Expression = {
            switch ($PSItem) {
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'CA' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'CANADA'} {
                    'Canada'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'LUX' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'LUXEMBOURG'} {
                    'Luxembourg'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'BRL' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'BRAZIL'} {
                    'Brazil'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'USA' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'US'} {
                    'America'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'UNITED KINGDOM' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'GB'} {
                    'United Kingdom'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'HONG KONG' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'HK'} {
                    'Hong Kong'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'INDIA' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'IN'} {
                    'India'
                }
                {$PSItem.Country -eq 'AUSTRALIA' -or $PSItem.DistinguishedName -eq 'AU'} {
                    'Australia'
                }
            }
        }
    }
) | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\UserList.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: It looks nice +1, but IMO the maintainability of such indented structures is difficult. Possibly OP better stuffs that into a function.

Comment: @LotPings Ideally, their `Get-ADUser` call would select the properties needed so this extra work with the select isn't necessary and just the two calculated properties are needed

Comment: I'm really surprised that you do not need more commas in there. It just looks weird to me. That and an objects DN would never look like that.

Comment: @Matt Commas are only necessary to separate values on the same line in the array literal.  Same thing applies to hashtables & semicolons.